# My Superior needs my presence but i have some obligation to do

Tags: communication

How To React to my superior if she/he need my presence but I have some obligation to do first?

Comment: Do the most basic thing one can do when it comes to conflict in interests. Talk to him, explain your situation and try to find a suitable solution for both of you.

Comment: I think you need to more fully explain the situation to get a satisfactory answer. The question as it stands is way too broad.

Comment: Is it a personal or work-related obligation (i.e. like another project needs your full attention) ? How does your superior need your presence? Is this about a certain meeting, i.e. time scale of hours, or is it about a day, a week?

Comment: What's the obligation? Is it that your presence is required at your wedding? Or do your friends on Facebook wait for a reply? Different obligation, different answer.

Comment: Tell him/her your obligation has higher priority. Wait, oh no, the superior's wish has higher priority. *How do **we** know if you do not tell us what the obligation is and why your presence is needed* ?

Comment: If it's a competing obligation for your job at this company, tell your superior about the conflict and ask him to clarify your priorities. If it's a personal obligation, then you have to consider the reasonableness of the boss's request versus the importance of the personal obligation. "My boss expects me to show up for a meeting during regular working hours but I wanted to drop by the bar and drink with my friends" is very different from "the boss tells me today that he wants me to work tomorrow, even though it's a weekend, but I was planning to go to my wife's funeral" is something else.

Answer (score 5):

> How To React to my superior if she/he need my presence but I have some
>   obligation to do first?

Talk to your superior first. Explain that you already have another obligation in that time period.

Ask if there is some other way to deal with it - perhaps handle it at another time, or have someone else help.

Then, make a decision based on her/his answer.

Comment: Your boss at this point will set the priority between his or her request and what you were planning for the same time. Do not be surprised if it is not the priority you would prefer. You will have to deal with the priority your boss sets. There are consequences for ignoring your boss' priorities. Especially if what you want to do is something personal that you didn't intend to tell him or her about.